# Windows NTFS partition disappeared from Disk Defragmenter

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, defragment

I've recently installed modded windows 8.1 version (it has some of the redundant features uninstalled to make it lighter and faster: [Polish forum link (they are good!](http://winclub.pl/topic/3705-windows-81-with-update-3-x86x64-marzec-2015-winclub-pl/)) It is running perfectly smooth alongside its normal counterpart and Linux system (elementaryOS).

But when I'm trying to "Defragment and Optimize my Drive", the data disk disappeared? What could be the reason of such behaviour? The program was run at normal Windows 8.1 system. It was there before an installation.

[image: partition layout]

The screen from the program running:
[image]

Apparently the D: drive is missing. When I'll come back from universtiy I'll check if it's visible on the 2nd modded system.

Comment: I assume you have restarted the system?  I also hope you have a backup of your data, there is a good chance, the partition is missing for a reason.

Comment: The partition exists and all three systems work fine. I only cannot see it in the "Defragment and optimize your Drives" program? In the interface itself.

Comment: You didn't indicate if a reboot fixed the problem or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't understood me corrctly. All three systems work fine. I've optimized them and use from a week or so. I've encoutered the problem when i launcher the "Defragment and Optimize your Drives" program (windows utility from Control Panel in normal windows 8.1). The data D: partition cannot be defragmented or analyzed since it is physically missing from the list (I've attached the picture). The D: drive exists and works (you can see it in a Disk Managament snapshot) but you cannot optimize it.

Comment: And i don't know why.

Comment: Have you used another program, something like [Defraggler](www.piriform.com/defraggler) to verify the problem exists with that software?  You still didn't indicate if you have tried to restart the system, you being able to access the drive, could simply be luck.

Comment: You should be able to get to it with Explorer/Disk Management -> Right-click -> Properties -> Tools.

Comment: @Ramhound The restart didn't help. I'll try dofferent software and the AFH's method when i get back home.

Comment: @AFH Nope, it just gets me to the same program I'm running all the time. Still can't see that partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, the Defraggler solved that issue. Thank you. However I want to leave the question unanswered, since I still do not know why that thing happened. Is the software buggy, is it restricted, did I mess up with sth (it doesn't look like but sure can be)? Thanks.